# How to redirect after reCAPTCHA verification?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Google reCAPTCHA on my site. If the captcha is success I want to redirect to another website.

The code I used is:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == "success") {
    function Redirect() {
      window.location = "example.com";
    }
    document.write("You will be
      redirected to a new page in 5 seconds ");      setTimeout('Redirect()',
      1000);
  }
  } else {
    alert("You can't proceed!");
</script>

<body>
  <div data-type="image" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="public site key"></div>
</body>
```

But it's not working.

Edited

I just don't understand JavaScript much . That's why I was asking and still don't understand it .
 What it means and what does I have to do with it. https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
Can you give me an example of whole code

Comment: Use the example from Google Recaptcha V2. The answer is there pretty much.

Comment: I just don't understand JavaScript much . That's why I was asking and still don't understand it .
 What it means and what does I have to do with it. https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify

Answer (score 0):

First thing is if you want to redirect use window.location.href = "example.com" and second you are showing user that page will redirect in 5 seconds but you are only setting 1 seconds time and third don't call the function in setTimeout only pass the function as callback to it. And please write this entire code as recaptcha's callback so that it can be called when recaptcha gets verified from server.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == "success") {
    function Redirect() {
      window.location.href = "example.com"; // Correct here
    }
    document.write("You will be redirected to a new page in 5 seconds ");      
      setTimeout(Redirect,5000); // Correct here
  }
  else alert("You can't proceed!");
</script>

<body>
  <div data-type="image" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="public site key"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried this. But it isn't working. I see no redirection